# Onchange event not triggered while using setattribute to select value of drop down

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, web-controls

I am trying to use windows form application to automate a few browser (internet explorer) tasks.

Here I am trying to select a value from the drop-down list available, which I have achieved by using `webbrowser1.set attribute("","")` option.

But once I have selected the option by this way the on change event of that drop down text box is not getting triggered whereas when I go back and select options manually its working fine.

Hence, here the on change event is not being triggered if I am using the set attribute option, so can someone suggest how I can select the required value and still trigger the onchange event.

Below is the snippet :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    webBrowser1.Document
               .GetElementById("ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ddl_Reports")
               .SetAttribute("value", "EmployeeInformationReport"); 
}
```

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You should attach to the eventhandler with the AttachEventHandler api of the document after the DocumentCompleted event:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.AttachEventHandler("nameoftheevent", eventHandler);
}
private void eventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do whatever you want
}
```